# Unpredicatable Block time in parachain?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, xcm, substrate-parachain-template

I connected two `parachains` with Relay chain. While working on `xcm` functionality, I discovered that block time of parachain changes. `Generally` block time of parachain in `parachain-node-template` is `12 sec`. Now I saw that sometimes the `block time` of parachain is `6 sec` and sometimes its `more than 12 sec`. All the transactions are executing successfully. Could anyone guide me why the block time in parachain keep on changing.